# Is there any good book(or reference) where van Kampen's theorem is explained in details?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Right now I'm studying  van Kampen 's Theorem

I have two hard copy book of topology .One is Hatcher and  another one is  Munkres Topology

But in Munkres topology ,van kampen theorem is not given

On the page No $40$  of  Hatcher book ,van Kampen 's Theorem  is given

But im finding difficulty  in Hatcher book

**My question** : Is there any good book(or reference)  where Van Kampen's theorem is   explained in details ?

Comment: Maybe [**Algebraic Topology: An Introduction**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387902716) by William S. Massey (1967; reprinted by Springer-Verlag in 1977), Chapter 4 -- *Seifert and Van Kampen Theorem on the Fundamental Group of the Union of Two Spaces. Applications* (pp. 113-144).

Comment: My copy of Munkres includes SVK in chapter 11

Comment: @DMcMor It is written that  **The Seifert-van** .I thought  ,that is not van kampen theorem .I means that the Seifert-van and van kampen theorem are different

Comment: @jasmine: "van Kampen" theorem is the same as "Seifert-van Kampen theorem" , just different authors use slightly different names. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Van_Kampen_theorem

Comment: Just a remark concerning the spelling of "van Kampen": *Egbert van Kampen* was a Dutch mathematician. The surname is "van Kampen", where the "van" is a [nobiliary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobiliary_particle) written with a lower-case "v". In English it is frequently (but erroneously) written with a capital "V".

Comment: okay sir @PaulFrost I edited

Comment: En dashes (–) such as that in "Seifert van–Kampen" (that is not an hyphen "-") are used to connect two names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest Ronald Brown's *Topology and Groupoids* (https://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) which gives a quite conceptual interpretation of the Seifert–van Kampen theorem: a "good" pushout diagram of topological spaces gives rise to a pushout diagram of fundamental groupoids. See section 6.7 and 9.1.